Anchor Screw Capacity:
Hello everyone,
I’ve calculated the anchor screw capacities (the screws that attach the orange piece to the concrete) based on the information I have, specifically focusing on tensile reactions. The reaction is influenced by the spacing between the screws, and since the total shear load is 180 lb, I divided it by the number of anchors to distribute the load evenly. However, I’m uncertain about the relationship between the tensile and shear loads. I assumed they combine to form a resultant force, but I’m not sure if that’s accurate.
Additionally, on the top part that holds the orange piece (Zone A), I need to perform the same calculations for the screws, but this time considering the shear force on all the components attached to the screws (including the wall and the orange piece).
Could anyone clarify how to properly combine tensile and shear loads in this context ? an how to calculate shear and Tensile Force on each componen mentionned above?
Thanks in advance!

Generally, one calculates stress to determine whether something will fail. While superposition applies, it should not result in a force without a given area.

let's call the screws and their distances from the right edge of the yellow fastener
$\text{S1,x1, S2, x2, S3, x3 , ( x1=L/4)}$
Each screw is subjected to two orthogonal shear loads, the horizontal shear $v=180/3$
the vertical shear has to balance the moment $M_{overtuning}= 180*H$:
The vertical shear on the screws will be proportional to their distance from the right edge.
$$v_3=3v_1 \ and \ v_2= 2 v_1 $$
$$\Sigma m_r=0  \Rightarrow x_1*v_1 = 2x_*v_2 = 3x_1*v_3= 180*H$$
$$x_1*v_1+ 2x_1*2v_1+3x_1*3v_1=14x_1v_1=180H$$
$$x_1v_=(180/14)H \Rightarrow L/4*v_1=12.85H$$
Each screw is subject to $60 lb$ horizontal and its contributory vertical shear $v1,\ v2=4v1,\ v3=9v1$ as per above.
The same thing happens to the vertical set of screws.
